# jquery: tired of css().css().css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parameters, styles

I'm really tired of syntax like this:

```
.css('position','absolute').css('z-index',z-index)
.css('border','1px solid #00AFFF').css('margin','-1px 0px 0px -1px')
.css('left',pleft)
```

I wonder if there's any way to pass all parameters in one function, something like:

```
.foo('position':'absolute','z-index':z-index,
     'border':'1px solid #00AFFF','margin':'-1px 0px 0px -1px',
     'left':pleft)
```

Much appreciate any help.

Comment: Fyi, your code is invalid. `z-index` is not a valid variable name but `z` minus `index` assuming both variables exist; otherwise it's an error.

Comment: It's for questions like this that http://api.jquery.com exists. Also, if you're making that many inline CSS changes, setup a stylesheet and simply use `addClass("myclass");`

Comment: yeah, it's was just an example... I never had such variables :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, pass an object to `.css()` (also [mentioned in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-map)):

```
.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: pleft,
    zIndex: 123
    ...
});
```

Note that you can use both syntaxes for the keys: `zIndex`, i.e. the camelcase version that can be used directly in JavaScript and `'z-index'` (quotes required as the `-` would break things otherwise).

For options that are always the same - in your case probably `position`, `border` and `margin` - it might be a good idea to a classic CSS rule set via a class/id selector. Then you'd just have to set the remaining (dynamic) options via `.css()`.

Answer (score 9):

Define style in separate class

css

```
.myCustomClass
{
     position: absolute;
     border: 1px solid #00AFFF
}
```

And js

```
.addClass('myCustomClass');
```

And this is very simple to manage if styles go too complex

Comment: Doesn't answer his question and doesn't work if he needs some dynamic values. He still needs `.css()` for them.

Comment: @ThiefMaster anyways, for certain situations this is pretty good solution, worth mentioning :)

Comment: that's correct ThiefMaster, I've been using classes for other purposes - but this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

```
$(element).css({'position':'absolute','z-index':zIndex,
     'border':'1px solid #00AFFF','margin':'-1px 0px 0px -1px',
     'left':pleft});
```